# Rails app cannot compile js : (No route matches [GET] "/packs/application-xxxx.js"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

my js is not compiled anymore on my rails app in development mode :

**Here is the console error :**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/packs/application-6b30daaa0a66e7f7c4fd.js 404 (Not Found)
```

**Here are my logs :**

```
Started GET "/packs/application-6b30daaa0a66e7f7c4fd.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-18 21:40:35 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/packs/application-6b30daaa0a66e7f7c4fd.js"):

actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
webpacker (3.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:18:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.3) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
puma (3.11.2) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

**Here are my package.json dependencies :**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
```

It was working perfectly fine before I played a bit with yarn and npm as I was trying to fix another bug. Do you have any idea of the problem?

Answer (score 20):

Did you run `./bin/webpack` before started the Rails server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer William! I finally found a solution :

Comment: This helped. What does it do?

Comment: Is the order matter? Got error even started before too

Comment: Yes, @SmartManoj you need to compile your webpacker, then all errors should disappear

Comment: @RubenPortz we need to compile only in production mode?

Comment: It’ll usually do this automatically when starting localhost, but you’re also able to start it yourself. 
Try running the line as stated in this answer and otherwise have a read through this article: https://prathamesh.tech/2019/08/26/understanding-webpacker-in-rails-6/ 

So try the following options @SmartManoj:
1. `./bin/webpack`
2. `./bin/webpack-dev-server` or
3. `Yarn`

Answer (score 3):

Run `bundle exec ./bin/webpack-dev-server` before starting rails s

Answer (score 1):

After hours, i found my error.

I was missing a comma in **environment.js** :

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

const webpack = require('webpack')
environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
    noUiSlider: 'nouislider'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
```

Thanks a lot everybody

Comment: at? which IDE u used?

Answer (score 0):

Try running in your terminal:

1. `./bin/webpack`
2. `./bin/webpack-dev-server` or
3. `Yarn`

The steps I run to start a new project are:

1. `git clone`
2. `bundle install`
3. `db:migrate`
4. `Yarn`
5. `Rails s`